# Symfony2 and bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have installed Symfony2 (last version) and trying to install bootstrap, but im always getting error from AppKernel

```
Fatal error: Class 'Braincrafted\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBootstrapBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fitnessBlog\app\AppKernel.php on line 20

Fatal error: Class 'Bc\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BcBootstrapBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fitnessBlog\app\AppKernel.php on line 11
```

As u can see i tried 2versions of bootstrap but still getting errors.
I'm so angry right now because i was searching in google about 2hours how to fix it and cant fidng problem or solution.

Comment: Did you run composer update after adding the bootstrap bundle?

Comment: Yes now, .less its missing so trying to figure out how to fix that..